# ToDoList - DOM elements with function. Replacing P-Tag with Input-Tag and vice versa. Need help to avoid nesting my functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I am trying to programm a ToDo-List. But I am trying it step by step and I am right at the beginning and facing a problem.

I have an `Input-Tag-Element` with a `keypress-event` function. 
Everytime I type something and press enter then the DOM creates a new `P-Tag-Element`. 
The inner html of this P is equal to the value of the input.

The `P-Tag-Elements` also have a `keypress-event`, in case we want to **edit** it later.
if I press on P Element then the DOM will replace this Element with a new input element.
The value of this new input is equal to the inner html of the p element which we repalced it with.

This Input elment hast a keypress function and if I press enter, it will be replaced with a new `P-Tag-Element`. And if you look at my code then you will see that all functions are nested. In my code after "**editing**" you can not **edit** it anymore unless you add another function inside this current function and if you want to stop **editing** . you have to add another function isndie the function adn so on.

I genuinely hope that someone got my idea and can help me. I found a way to solve it, but I dont like it. I put the p elements inside a div tag and added a click event to the div tag. Whenever I clicked on the div tag it looks for the first child and if its a`P-Tag-Element` it repalces it with a `Input-Tag-Element` and vice versa. But that cant be the solution. Using this solution feels like running away from a problem which you are going to face anyways soon again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Titel</title>
    <style>
        input,
        p {
            display: block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="display"></div>  <!-- My Start Display  -->

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", evt => {

            const ausgabe = document.querySelector('#display');

            const DOMElementCreate = ({  // creating my DOOM Ibjects with function
                content = '',
                typ = 'div',
                events = {},
                parent = display
            } = {}) => {
                let newElement = document.createElement(typ);
                newElement.innerHTML = content;
                newElement.value = content;
                Object.entries(events).forEach(event => newElement.addEventListener(...event));
                parent.append(newElement);
                return newElement;
            }


            DOMElementCreate({  // creating input-element with a keypress function
                typ: 'input',
                events: {
                    keypress: function (event) {
                        if (event.key === "Enter") {

                            DOMElementCreate({   // creating p-element with a click function
                                typ: 'p',
                                content: this.value,
                                events: {
                                    click: function (event) {

                                        this.replaceWith(DOMElementCreate({  // replacing p-element with new input element with keypress function
                                            typ: "input",
                                            content: this.innerHTML,
                                            events: {
                                                keypress: function (event) {
                                                    if (event.key === "Enter") {

                                                        this.replaceWith(DOMElementCreate({  // replacing input-element with new P element
                                                            typ: "p",
                                                            content: this.value
                                                        }));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }));
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the infinite nesting with a global event-handler that deals with enter-presses in conjunction with the [`contendeditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute on the paragraphs you are creating.

Here is a simple implementation:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

window.onkeydown = ({ key, target }) => {
    if (key === 'Enter') {
        // prevent linebreaks in our paragraphs and stop editing them on enter
        if (target !== input) {
            target.blur();
        } else if (input.value) {
            document.body.append(Para(input.value));
            input.value = '';
        }
    }
}

function Para(value) {
    const p = document.createElement('p');    
    return Object.assign(p, {
        textContent: value,
        contentEditable: true
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not thought of this at all. But I was wondering how to solve my example  with new elements. Maybe I change P tag to Label and vice versa. could you help me here?

Comment: @dahood I updated my answer to give you some pointers. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. Will take this into consideration :))